# Firefox Web Developer, Inpector window. How can you copy a fully expanded calculated page?

Tags: html, debugging, firefox

I'm in the Firefox 'Web Developer' 'Inspector' frame/window and I want to copy a fully expanded display.  How do I do that?  I tried 'expand all' and a 'ctl a'; but no go.

(Some tool!  I don't know what half of it does! - learning)

Comment: What?  lol...Why don't you just "view source"?  Get out of the Inspect element frame/window and simply right click anywhere on page and then click the -> "View page source"

Comment: It's not rendered fully.

Comment: I'm noticing that a lot of dialogs don't allow you to copy.  @#$@#$

Comment: What do you mean with "fully expanded  calculated page/display"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you call it, but the inspector window is like a 'collapsing' editor.   Much of code is hidden until you expand it by tapping a small arrow icon on the left.  The lol post assumed that 'view source' (right click page) showed the page as finally rendered.  It does not.  But the inspector window shows it as it really is.  I want to print that window with all code fully 'expanded'.  I waiting for my 'doh! moment.  It's probably so easy to do.  Thanks.

Comment: @Michael `view source` gives you the initial page that was returned from the response. And all the changes on it after running your scripts, loading some contents via ajax are not considered in it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the Firefox developer Inspector,you can copy paste the code in the following way.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML)

- If you want to copy the **full html** then,select your **html** tag in the inspector.
  A *`context menu`* will show.Simply `Ctrl C` and `Ctrl V` your *code*.Or *right click* and *select* the **edit as html** option and then *copy* your *desired text*.It will always show the *full expanded view* as you desire.

***Alternatively***

- If you want to copy any child element then select the contents of the tag you want to copy and simply right click and select the edit as inner html and then copy the desired text.

*Applicable for all.

Comment: ... the only thing I didn't try.  Thank you.  I'm going to hide this some how.  DOH!

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  I thought you got the money when I checked it.  Thanks.  Was that the easiest 50 you ever made?  Thanks again.

Comment: yea, always there to help m8 :)